# Reduce file path when calling a file from terminal

Tags: macos, lua, terminal

I'm using Lua in *interactive mode* on a Mac (thanks to rudix.org).

When I want to load a file I do:

```
dofile("/my/long/path/to/my/directory/file.lua")
```

I want to do a different thing, that is:

1. put all my files in a desktop directory `myDirectory`;
2. then call the file from the terminal this way `dofile("file.lua")`;

Is this possible? How?

Comment: Put what files in a desktop directory?

Comment: Files with .lua extension

Answer (score 1):

If the path is fixed, you can just redefine `dofile`:

```
local _dofile=dofile
local path=("/my/long/path/to/my/directory/") 
function dofile(x)
    return _dofile(path..x)
end
```

You may put this (and other initializations) in a file and set the environment variable `LUA_INIT` to its location. After this, every invocation of `lua` will see the version of `dofile` redefined above and the users will be able to say simply `dofile("foo.lua")`.

Alternatively, you can use `require`, which looks for modules in a list of paths in `package.path` or `LUA_PATH`.

Comment: This is interesting but the problem is related to a classroom: I can't have children copying long paths while teaching. I was looking for something like an environment variable

Comment: And, in fact, my current altenative is require   :-)